# Who is the other asteroid head in the end credits?

Tags: theme-song, sabagebu

In the end track of *Sabagebu!* there are some asteroids floating around in the shape of  character's heads.

The first one is Platy, the Platypus:

[image]

The next one is our lead heroine Momoka:

[image]

But who is this last face? It doesn't look like anyone and there's not exactly a large male cast to choose from (assuming the face is male). The first time it's shown, it appears to have facial hair (although it could just be shadow), whereas later on it disappears:

[image]
[image]

Any ideas who that's supposed to be? ...it's kinda creepy

Comment: Remembered me of some plush I saw at a convention. [monkey plush](http://i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/v8/366586952/big_mouth_monkey_cartoon_anime_USB_flash.jpg) don't know what they are called, and this is the only picture I could find. But it might help